# Reordering SlickGrid Columns Resets Column Header HTML

Tags: grid, slickgrid, columnheader

I have a grid of data where we have added a filter icon to the header of each column after initializing the grid like so:

```
function selectHeaderIcon(searchActive){
        if (searchActive) {
            return "ui-icon-zoomin";
        } else {
            return "ui-icon-search";
        }
    }

function updateColumnHeader(searchActive){
        self.grid.updateColumnHeader(column.id, name + '<span class="ui-icon '+selectHeaderIcon(searchActive)+' slick-resizable-handle searchLink  ' + columnCss + '" ></span>', 'Search');
    }
```

I have also enabled column reordering on the grid.  However, whenever I reorder the columns, my search icons disappear!  I did some further testing in chrome debugger by manually adding text to change a column name as well as adding a random new span to the html.  After reordering the columns, both changes disappeared.  Is SlickGrid storing a different copy of my column headers somewhere instead of using what is displayed to do the reordering?  If so, why?  How do I get around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to subscribe to the onColumnsReordered event, something like the following:

```
GridName.onColumnsReordered.subscribe(function(e, args) {
    updateColumnHeader(searchActive);
});
```